# Python inequality comparison dealing with floating point precision

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, floating-accuracy, inequality

I need to compare floating point numbers with inequalities:

```py
if x >= y:
```

However, due to floating point precision issues, sometimes this fails when it should succeed (`x = 0.21` and `y= 0.21000000000000002`). I was thinking to create an epsilon:

```py
epsilon = 0.000000001
if x >= y - epsilon:
```

I'd rather use a standard mechanism for this. Python has a `math.isclose` function that works for equality, but I couldn't find anything for inequality. So I have to write something like this:

```py
import math

if x > y or math.isclose(x, y):
```

I have to do this a *ton* in my application... easy enough, I'll just create a function. My question is if there's a standard way to deal with inequalities and floats? Is there a `numpy.greater_or_equal(x, y)` type function?

Comment: Since you're really just looking for a `greater_than_or_close(x, y)`, why not simply define that function? Is the overhead unacceptable?

Comment: @Grismar it's not the overhead. This seems like one of those functions that I can get wrong easily due to surprising floating point precision issues, despite seeming very straightforward (`x >= y` seemed very straightforward). Or there's a more efficient way to do this (that would just be the tiniest of a bonus). In general I try and find standard functions for this type of thing so that there's less code, maintenance, and training of other developers on the code.

Comment: `x > y or isclose(x, y)` is equivalent to `x - y > -max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)`, or, filling in the default tolerances and simplifying slightly, `x - y > -1e-9 * max(abs(a), abs(b))`. This is not an endorsement of using `math.isclose` or this test; using `math.isclose` is an indication that something in an application is badly designed, especially when it is used with the default tolerances.

Answer (score -1):

Since you indicated that the overhead of a function call is not really an issue, why not simply provide:

```
def greater_than_or_close(x: float, y: float) -> bool:
    from math import isclose
    return x > y or isclose(x, y)
```

You can import that wherever you need it.

Your comments stated: "This seems like one of those functions that I can get wrong easily due to surprising floating point precision issues", but since this only relies on `x` actually being greater than `y`, or using the `math.isclose()` function, that risks seems to be absent?

(or rather, keeping the import outside the function:)

```
import math


def greater_than_or_close(x: float, y: float) -> bool:
    return x > y or math.isclose(x, y)
```

Comment: This is what they've shown/mentioned in the question already. What they're asking is whether there's a "standard way", and I don't see you addressing that question at all.

Comment: I'd argue defining the function is the standard way, more so because they already provided the more efficient, but less readable alternative themselves.

Comment: They also already provided the define-a-function idea ("easy enough, I'll just create a function").